# Cache controller/action

Tags: plugin-development, cache, controller

Does Craft have a built-in Controller/action for clearing the cache?
We have auto-deployment set to a server and would be useful to set up a POST-receive hook to force the cache to clear when deployments are made.

Comment: Which caches are you wanting to clear? Template caches? General data cache (`craft->cache`)? Asset caches? All of the above?

Comment: Yes, template caches primarily although asset might be useful in case assets are being pushed up (thought we generally tend to keep these out of our repos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to write a [super-simple plugin](https://pluginfactory.io/) that exposes a controller's action URL your deploy hook could hit.  That action would basically just mimic what the [ClearCachesTool](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/tools/ClearCachesTool.php) does for clearing the various caches in Craft.

E.g. [Template caches](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/tools/ClearCachesTool.php#L123), [Asset Transform Index caches](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/tools/ClearCachesTool.php#L128), [Asset Index caches](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/tools/ClearCachesTool.php#L133), [general data caches](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/tools/ClearCachesTool.php#L110), etc.